# Reason for inserting column value in SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

Friends,
   I am inserting the xml parsed data into database table,i have the following fields,
name,price,image,

1. Static insert of name
   addevent("name",price,image);
   it's getting inserted well,where i given name field has static.

2.Dynamic insert of names.
But when insert the field data from xml parsed value (name) - String ,
it's being inserted has null value in the table or it's blank value.

table field data types,
  name  TEXT, price TEXT,image TEXT.
Help me fix this problem.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to insert your dynamic data? Paste the code you are using to insert dynamic data.
Are you putting quotes around the "dynamic data"?

Regards,

Sarwar Erfan